# substitute nested foreachs with lambdas c#

Tags: c#, lambda, foreach

would it be possible to express the following block of code with lambdas instead of foreachs?

```
    IEnumerable<BODSurveys.SurveysAnwer> resp = new List<SurveysAnwer>();
    foreach (var section in Sections)
    {
      foreach (var question in section.Questions)
      {
        foreach (var answer in question.SurveysAnwers)
        {
          yield return answer;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: What tangible benefit do you expect to see by using lambda functions?

Comment: @Ron, less indentation. More expressive. Functional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes:

```
return Sections.SelectMany(s => s.Questions.SelectMany(q => q.SurveyAnswers));
```